# Measure thickness of a shaper in different points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

The goal is to analyze an image containing a continuous, thick black zigzag line that forms a rectangular shape. This zigzag line's thickness varies along its length, and the task is to measure and report this thickness variation.

The image is showcasing a example of the data I have, even there is no thickness changes in this image.

I tried several direct approach.

Approach number 1 :

Preprocess the Image:

Contour Detection:

Slice the Contour:

Drawing bounding box for each slice.

Counting black pixels (tried to re oriented the the bounding box into horizontals to count pixel by columns).

aproach number 2:

"unroll" or straighten the zigzag line that forms a rectangular shape into a horizontal one. This involves transforming the vertical components of the zigzag into horizontal segments while maintaining the connectivity of the pattern.

[image]

Comment: Hey, this is your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78145255/how-to-measure-the-thicknesswidth-of-the-the-black-line-along-it-all-length. I again ask you to please read the how to ask and give us a reproducible example where we can see that you tried something and it did not work. Currently, your questions reads like a request to solve a task that you did not even attempt. You have the python tag, and you did not even include any python code in your question.

Comment: If "thickness values along its length" is needed,
You should define the "length" of black zigzag line : length of where?
Inner perimeter? Outer perimeter? or center?

Comment: Then, extract the sequence of measurement positions depends on your definition. Size of the sequence(number of positions) equals to the "length".
After that, measure "thickness" at each measurement positions. Orientation of "thickness" can be estimated from the curve(sequence)'s local shape, or gradient of pixel value(intensity) etc.